# What is just happening to my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

I was at 1080 today in the evening and I suddenly saw that my reputation dropped down to 784 without any notification. I have been active only for 7 days. And even my individual daily reputations add up to 1082.

Today it was 1387 but dropped in the afternoon with a message that voting-reviewed where they told me that someone might have visited my account and repeatedly voted up to my answers and that is perfectly fine that you should fix that.

[image]

But I don't know why are they just lowering my reputation without any notice. Is that a glitch or did I do something wrong? Or do they want me to leave Math SE? I don't think I have offended or abused someone... Why is the community doing this to me without any notification?

[image]

Comment: When you wrote " lowering my notifications", did you mean " lowering my reputation"?

Comment: When you write about your reputation, do you check how your reputation is displayed [on main](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/823370/soumyadwip-chanda) or [on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/823370/soumyadwip-chanda). The reputation on meta usually lags a bit behind the reputation on the main site. (Although I do not remember seeing such big difference.) There was this bug report on [meta.se] some time ago, but I am not sure whether it might be related or not: [Meta sites in “Your Communities” display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317269).

Comment: I see -378 on your reputation tab for serial voting corrected.

Comment: Well... they have fixed that... I am back to 1125

Comment: @MattSamuel I guess I mentioned that

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think anyone wants you to leave Math S.E. The high average score of your answers (especially the recent ones) show that you have been helpful to many people, and it would be a shame to lose you.

Comment: What most likely happened is that someone visited your profile, then upvoted 38 of your answers and downvoted 1 within a short time frame. This will cause the system to automatically reverse the votes because a user who behaves like that could be a bot.

Comment: Yes... But even after that there was some other glitch maybe in the system. They have fixed it now and I m back to 1125.

Comment: Ok there was a similar reputation change under voting correction. But I don't think they have fixed it back. I had long back via flagged about some spurious upvotes, but it was not that much.

Answer (score 5):

The top menu bar does not notify you of reputation losses [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219652/why-do-reputation-drops-not-highlight-the-achievements-icon/219665#219665). You may argue that this should be different, and indeed there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements) on global meta for this.